# A Prolog program for permutation parity

Tags: prolog, permutation, parity

I wrote this small program in Prolog.

```
odd_even_flip(odd, even).
odd_even_flip(even, odd).

% flip_one, for A = a, B = b, P = [a, .., b, ..], gives M = [b, .., a, ..]
flip_one(A, B, P, M) :-
    append([A|As], [B|Bs], P),
    append([B], As, L),
    append([A], Bs, R),
    append(L, R, M).
    
permutation_parity([X|L], [X|P], R) :- permutation_parity(L, P, R).
% abc
permutation_parity([X|L], [Y|P], R) :-
    X \= Y,
    flip_one(Y, X, [Y|P], M),
    permutation_parity([X|L], M, Res),
    odd_even_flip(Res, R).
permutation_parity([], [], even).
```

I expect it to find the parity of a permutation P of list L. The few queries that assert that a given permutation of a given list is indeed even or odd worked fine.

However, from my experience with Prolog, I would expect that permutation_parity([a, b, c], X, Y). would show me all permutations of [a, b, c] but that is not happening.

Rather, I get X = [a, b, c], Y = even. and that is all.

I tried to add member(Y, L) in the rule that follows %abc as I was thinking that will help Prolog to know how to instantiate X in permutation_parity([a, b, c], X, Y) but that helped to no avail.

If someone could help me see what I am missing it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question should have a decent-sized list of intended inputs and expected outputs, to clarify the text.

Comment: I think I'm happy with slago's answer to what I was asking. but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use unification to correctly instantiate the variable `X` (assuming that `permutation_parity/3` is called with a proper list as its first argument). So I suggest you modify your code as follows:

```
permutation_parity([], [], even).
permutation_parity([X|Xs], [X|Zs], P) :-
    permutation_parity(Xs, Zs, P).
permutation_parity([X|Xs], Zs, P) :-
    permutation_parity(Xs, Ys, Q),
    flip_first([X|Ys], Zs),
    odd_even_flip(Q, P).

flip_first(L0, L1) :-
    append([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], L0),
    append([Y|Xs], [X|Ys], L1).

odd_even_flip(odd, even).
odd_even_flip(even, odd).
```

Examples:

```
?- permutation_parity([a,b,c], Permutation, Parity).
Permutation = [c, a, b],
Parity = even ;
Permutation = [b, c, a],
Parity = even ;
Permutation = [b, a, c],
Parity = odd ;
Permutation = [c, b, a],
Parity = odd ;
Permutation = [a, c, b],
Parity = odd ;
Permutation = [a, b, c],
Parity = even.

?- permutation_parity([a,b,c], [a,c,b], Parity).
Parity = odd ;
false.

?- permutation_parity([a,b,c], Permutation, even).
Permutation = [c, a, b] ;
Permutation = [b, c, a] ;
Permutation = [a, b, c].
```

**EDIT**

```
perm_parity(L0, L1, P) :-
    same_length(L0, L1),
    permutation_parity(L0, L1, P).
```

The predicate [same_length/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=same_length/2) is defined in SWI-Prolog as follows:

```
same_length([], []).
same_length([_|T1], [_|T2]) :-
    same_length(T1, T2).
```

Example:

```
?- perm_parity(L, [a,b,c], P).
L = [b, c, a],
P = even ;
L = [c, a, b],
P = even ;
L = [b, a, c],
P = odd ;
L = [c, b, a],
P = odd ;
L = [a, c, b],
P = odd ;
L = [a, b, c],
P = even.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The code you provided does what I expect it to do. I need to study the difference between the two programs to better understand what is happening. Perhaps as I continue studying I will get a better understanding of how to use unification. Thanks again.

Comment: One more thing. permutation_parity([a, b, c], X, Parity) gives in X all permutations of [a, b, c].
I think that permutation_parity(X, [a, b, c], Parity). should do the same. The code you wrote hangs after the first value of X is found. Is my expectation wrong, or is this something that should be doable?

Comment: As I've said, the correct instantiation of the variable `X` depends on the first argument of the predicate `permutation_parity/3` being instantiated to a proper list (that argument cannot be an uninstantiated variable). Anyway, you can define a wrapping predicate to guarantee that condition, as shown in **EDIT**.

Comment: Can fix the "hang" with e.g. https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/bidirectional-reverse-3-wanted/5931/2 method.